# Using android login template correctly

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and java and am trying to setup a login page that posts to a webpage that verifies the credentials and returns a cookie.

I am using the login template included with eclipse. I am not sure what to put for the

// TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

All I need it so post to my page like this: www.mywebsite.com/login?userid=john&password=test

and if the credentials are correct I get a json success string and cookie back. How can I incorporate this into this template or what do i need to put in place of the authentication against a network service

```
    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

            try {
                // Simulate network access.
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return false;
            }

            for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
                String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
                if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                    // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                    return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
                }
            }

            // TODO: register the new account here.
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);

            if (success) {
                finish();
            } else {
                mPasswordView
                        .setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
        }
    }
}
```

**edit:** I tried searching for an example of this but did not find one that fit my case. Any links to a solution or example of what im trying to do are appreciated.

Comment: What you get back from your Web service if login credential right?

Comment: What they're referring to with that comment is logging into an authentication service of your own or an external one like google play, facebook, oauth etc.

Comment: @MD I get a cookie back and a json string that success=True

Comment: @Durandal Yes I get that but what I dont know is how do I do that or what is an example of what I would put in there

Comment: @BluGeni This is one for google play: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16358907/772385 and here's one for facebook: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-2